# Initializing a vector with "itself" works with MSVC2013, not with GCC 4.8.1

Tags: c++, gcc

The following code prints `0` with GCC 4.8.1 (why not) but `10` with MSVC2013 (why?):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

const int y = 10;

int main()
{
  std::vector<double> y(y);
  std::cout << y.size() << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Undefined behaviour. Both are right.

Comment: Try clang: `t.cpp:8:25: warning: variable 'y' is uninitialized when used within its own initialization [-Wuninitialized]` at `std::vector<double> y(y);`

Comment: @mat: clang seems to be the smart one^^.

Comment: @chris: how could MSVC2013 use / find y=10 here?

Comment: @Korchkidu Since this is UB MSVC can do what ever it wants with this code, including guessing you meant the global `y` and use it or impregnate your cat.

Comment: @Korchkidu: undefined behavior - you can't reason about it. Might be picking up random cruft on the stack. Might be hardcoded to try and give you a value you never expect.

Comment: @Korchkidu, If it's ignoring the local and using global, that worries me a bit. Otherwise, as said, UB can mean anything, and Clang is often good at telling you about it. Anyway, if you'd like to test the validity of MSVC on the local vs. global thing, try running [this](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/81953c9b75dd6325). `p` should be the same output as `&p`.

Comment: Neither gcc 4.7.2 nor gcc 4.9.0 give a single warning for this code even though I passed `-Wall -Wextra -std=c++11 -pedantic`. This is somewhat disappointing. :( By the way, the generated executable crashes as `std::bad_alloc` is thrown.

Comment: What does MSVC tell you with [`/W4`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/thxezb7y.aspx)?

Comment: @ali: MSVC tells nothing with /W4 nor /Wall...

Comment: @Malloc: Indeed, as it is UB, MSVC can do whatever it wants. However, I would expect compiler to highlight UBs by returning completely wrong values instead of trying to "repair / hide" them;) These are design choices I have a hard time to understand actually;) Thanks!

Comment: @chris: you are the most upvoted comment. Could you make it an answer with some additonal reference to the C++ standard (and I will accept it) please?

Comment: @Korchkidu Thanks for the info! Yeah, it is quite disappointing. :(

Comment: @Korchkidu, I think there's a pretty relevant question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9820027/using-newly-declared-variable-in-initialization-int-x-x1), actually.

Comment: @chris: while double y[y] is ok, std::vector<double> y(y) is not. Most probably because the vector is first declared, and then initialized. This may be somehow related indeed. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

i think you need compile with 
`warning level 4 or warning is an error` in visual studio and
`-Wall and -Werror or -Winit-self or -Wuninitialized` for ggcc.
That compile, but you have an allocation problem.

For me the best flags are : 
`-std=c++11 -pipe -m64 -ansi -fPIC -g -O3 -fno-exceptions -fstack-protector -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now -fvisibility=hidden -W -Wall -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-unused-function -Wno-unused-label -Wpointer-arith -Wformat -Wreturn-type -Wsign-compare -Wmultichar -Wformat-nonliteral -Winit-self -Wuninitialized -Wno-deprecated -Wformat-security -Werror`

Comment: Did you check that gcc gives a warning with your flags? Please check!