# Is passing a C++ object into its own constructor legal?

Tags: c++, class, constructor, language-lawyer, undefined-behavior

I am surprised to accidentally discover that the following works:

```
#include <iostream>            
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  struct Foo {
    Foo(Foo& bar) {
      std::cout << &bar << std::endl;
    }
  };
  Foo foo(foo); // I can't believe this works...
  std::cout << &foo << std::endl; // but it does...
}
```

I am passing the address of the constructed object into its own constructor. This looks like a circular definition at the source level. Do the standards really allow you to pass an object into a function before the object is even constructed or is this undefined behavior?

I suppose it's not that odd given that all class member functions already have a pointer to the data for their class instance as an implicit parameter. And the layout of the data members is fixed at compile time.

Note, I'm NOT asking if this is useful or a good idea; I'm just tinkering around to learn more about classes.

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour Why did you delete your answer? Just add a quotation of [basic.life]p6 for restrictions.

Comment: Yes, that's fine; it's essentially the same as using `this` in a constructor, with all its pitfalls.

Comment: Isn't this more like `size_t x = sizeof(x)` ? The constructor of an object is called at a point where the memory is allocated (from an unspecified source). As long as you only depend on properties of the storage, and not on any value interpretation, things should be safe.

Comment: @MSalters There's a subtle question as to whether or not the storage is allocated *prior to binding the object to the reference*, which is before the constructor call.

Comment: @dyp: Considering that an **object** cannot exist outside of storage, I don't see how that could happen. Values can exist outside of storage, but even a const reference cannot be bound to such a value. Instead a temporary object will be constructed in storage, and the const ref binds to that temporary object.

Comment: Shafik, at your suggestion, I temporarily unaccepted your answer, though it was already plenty deep for me :)

Comment: The OP's example is a variation on `struct X {}; X foo(X&) { return X(); } X x = foo(x);` but without the indirection through an unrelated function. It's valid as far as syntax goes, and I think is valid semantically as long as you don't use the object through the reference ([class.cdtor] seems relevant) ... but it's certainly dangerous ground and not a good idea!

Comment: @MSalters The example I had in mind was that an implementation might check when initializing a reference that it refers to allocated storage (and not unallocated storage). This particular DS9K implementation allocates storage just prior to calling a constructor, so we get a sequence: reference binding -> allocation -> constructor call. (Alternatively, the computation of the storage address might be postponed until the actual allocation, so the reference binding is impossible.)

Comment: In the code this evolved from, I was capturing the value in a lambda by reference, but decided the question had nothing to do with lambdas.

Comment: @dyp: I've got a bit of a problem understanding exactly what you mean by "reference binding" and "allocated storage". Considering your "DS9K" implementation, what is the difference between the state before binding the reference and the state directly afterwards but before the allocation?

Comment: Since you're just trying to learn more about classes, I'd like to note that passing a reference of an object in the constructor is how a [Copy Constructor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copy_constructor_%28C%2B%2B%29) is created.  Your constructor as written is a valid declaration of a copy constructor (of course the body of your ctor is not copying...).

Comment: @MSalters In my DS9K implementation, this sequence leads to an invalid state; it is illegal to have a reference to unallocated storage. Consider an implementation that places complete objects on the heap, and therefore can only compute the address of an object with automatic storage duration after it has been allocated (on the heap). Furthermore, consider this allocation happens immediately before the execution of the constructor, which is after the *attempt* of binding `foo` to a reference in the OP. Ref-binding in such an implementation needs to compute the address and store it in a pointer.

Comment: @dyp: Looks like an implementation bug then. What is the state of the reference before the heap allocation? How is that state a "reference binding" to the future object? Remember that the C++ Standard describes an abstract implementation that your actual implementation has to match. The abstract implementation creates objects in allocated storage, which may fail (exception). Therefore allocated storage logically has to exist prior to object creation.

Comment: @MSalters I seem not to be able to convey my point: The Standard says it's *legal* to (form and) use a reference to an object *after the storage of said object has been allocated*, but fails to specify *exactly when the storage of said object is allocated*. So I'm trying to come up with some weird implementation, where the allocation happens too late - that is, after the attempt to form a reference, but prior to the constructor call, which would make the example invalid in that implementation.

Comment: It seems like maybe an analogous example is `int construct(int *p) { ... }; int x = construct(&x);` which is perfectly fine as long as `construct(p)` does not dereference `p`.  This seems easier to understand for me.

Comment: `Foo foo(foo);` doesn't call the constructor directly, first `Foo foo` allocate memory, then `Foo(foo)` call the constructor with a reference to the allocated memory.

Comment: I know I asked you to unaccept because I was not sure about my answer but I am sure now. Do you need further clarification?

Answer (score 68):

This is not undefined behavior. Although `foo` is uninitialized, you are using it a way that is allowed by the standard. After space is allocated for an object but before it is fully initialized, you are allowed to use it limited ways. Both binding a reference to that variable and taking its address are allowed.

This is covered by [defect report 363: Initialization of class from self](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_closed.html#363)  which says:

> And if so, what is the semantics of the self-initialization of UDT?
>   For example
>
> ```
>  #include <stdio.h>
>
>  struct A {
>         A()           { printf("A::A() %p\n",            this);     }
>         A(const A& a) { printf("A::A(const A&) %p %p\n", this, &a); }
>         ~A()          { printf("A::~A() %p\n",           this);     }
>  };
>
>  int main()
>  {
>   A a=a;
>  }
> ```
>
> can be compiled and prints:
>
> ```
> A::A(const A&) 0253FDD8 0253FDD8
> A::~A() 0253FDD8
> ```

and the resolution was:

> 3.8 [basic.life] paragraph 6 indicates that the references here are valid. It's permitted to take the address of a class object before it is fully initialized, and it's permitted to pass it as an argument to a reference parameter as long as the reference can bind directly. Except for the failure to cast the pointers to void * for the %p in the printfs, these examples are standard-conforming.

The full quote of section `3.8` *[basic.life]* from the draft C++14 standard is as follows:

> Similarly, before the lifetime of an object has started but after the
>   storage which the object will occupy has been allocated or, after the
>   lifetime of an object has ended and before the storage which the
>   object occupied is reused or released, any glvalue that refers to the
>   original object may be used but only in limited ways. For an object
>   under construction or destruction, see 12.7. Otherwise, such a glvalue
>   refers to allocated storage (3.7.4.2), and using the properties of the
>   glvalue that do not depend on its value is well-defined. The program
>   has undefined behavior if:
>
> - an lvalue-to-rvalue conversion (4.1) is applied to such a glvalue,
> - the glvalue is used to access a non-static data member or call a non-static member function of the
>     object, or
> - the glvalue is bound to a reference to a virtual base class (8.5.3), or
> - the glvalue is used as the operand of a dynamic_cast (5.2.7) or as the operand of typeid.

We are not doing anything with `foo` that falls under undefined behavior as defined by the bullets above.

If we try this with Clang, we see an ominous warning (*[see it live](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/r91TJdb8tVqSnuPG)*):

> warning: variable 'foo' is uninitialized when used within its own initialization [-Wuninitialized]

It is a valid warning since [producing an indeterminate value from an uninitialized automatic variable is undefined behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23415661/1708801). However, in this case you are just binding a reference and taking the address of the variable within the constructor, which does not produce an indeterminate value and is valid. On the other hand, the [following self-initialization example from the draft C++11 standard](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14935722/1708801):

```
int x = x ;
```

does invoke undefined behavior.

[Active issue 453: References may only bind to “valid” objects](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_active.html#453)  also seems relevant but is still open. The initial proposed language is consistent with Defect Report 363.

Comment: Ah, ok :) (Somehow I didn't think about that and took it for granted.) Nevertheless, I think there's a small detail missing in the Standard.

Comment: @dyp: It's indeed not precisely specified, but it must be _ordered before_ the first base class constructor starts executing. You just can't determine how much before.

Comment: Thanks Shafik! The people hanging out on Stack Overflow, and the ability of the site to put the right questions in front of the right eyes never ceases to amaze me!

Comment: Sorry, I was talking about the Original Post / the question. Anyway, thinking about it again, I might have misunderstood the "constructed" part. I thought OP meant we're passing a *constructed object* into the constructor for that object, whereas in fact we're passing an *uninitialized object* into the constructor.

Answer (score 16):

The constructor is called at a point where memory is allocated for the object-to-be. At that point, no object exists at that location (or possibly an object with a trivial destructor). Furthermore, the `this` pointer refers to that memory and the memory is properly aligned.

Since it's allocated and aligned memory, we may refer to it using lvalue expressions of `Foo` type (i.e. `Foo&`). What we may *not* yet do is have an lvalue-to-rvalue conversion. That's only allowed after the constructor body is entered.

In this case, the code just tries to print `&bar` inside the constructor body. It would even be legal to print `bar.member` here. Since the constructor body has been entered, a `Foo` object exists and its members may be read.

This leaves us with one small detail, and that's name lookup. In `Foo foo(foo)`, the first `foo` introduces the name in scope and the second `foo` therefore refers back to the just-declared name. That's why `int x = x` is invalid, but `int x = sizeof(x)` is valid.

Comment: But I didn't get any error while compiling `int x = x` with g++ 4.8. Invalid statement should spit error, right?

Comment: @cbinder: _Should_, but unfortunately not _will_.

Answer (score 0):

As said in other answers, an object can be initialized with itself as long as you do not use its values before they are initialized. You can still bind the object to a reference or take its address.
But beyond the fact that it is valid, let's explore a usage example.

The example below might be controversial, you can surely propose many other ideas for implementing it. And yet, it presents a valid usage of this strange C++ property, that you can pass an object into its own constructor.

```
class Employee {
   string name;
   // manager may change so we don't hold it as a reference
   const Employee* pManager; 
public:
  // we prefer to get the manager as a reference and not as a pointer
  Employee(std::string name, const Employee& manager)
    : name(std::move(name)), pManager(&manager) {}

  void modifyManager(const Employee& manager) {
      // TODO: check for recursive connection and throw an exception
      pManager = &manager;
  }

  friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const Employee& e) {
      out << e.name << " reporting to: ";
      if(e.pManager == &e)
        out << "self";
      else
        out << *e.pManager;
      return out;
  }
};
```

Now comes the usage of initializing an object with itself:

```
// it is valid to create an employee who manages itself
Employee jane("Jane", jane);
```

In fact, with the given implementation of class Employee, the user has no other choice but to initialize the first Employee ever created, with itself as its own manager, as there is no other Employee yet that can be passed. And in a way that makes sense, as the first employee created should manage itself.

Code: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9c397bce622eeacd