# How to create an object of a class with its own object as parameter in constructor?

Tags: c++

Is it is possible to create an object of a class like below which does not have any parameterless constructor?
Passing null pointer is not an option I think.

```
class MyClass
{
public:
    MyClass(MyClass* myClass)
    {
        //do something
    };
};
```

Comment: Question is why do you need that?

Comment: "_Passing null pointer is not an option I think._": Why not?

Comment: If a `nullptr` is not an option, you're better off passing in the argument as a reference; at that point you've just created the copy constructor with extra steps.

Comment: You might need a nullptr to create the first object, and then pass that on when creating the next one. For example, a linked list might end in a nullptr.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32608458/is-passing-a-c-object-into-its-own-constructor-legal

Comment: You *could* say `MyClass x(&x);` but you can't do anything with that object in the constructor. Is this an academic exercise, or are you planning to actually do this?

Comment: Hmm. How would you create the object whose address you pass to the constructor that creates another object? At some point, there must be an "original", is not?

Comment: the title is not quite clear. "with its own object as parameter" do you want to create an object called `a` and pass `&a` as parameter to the constructor? Or is the question merely about the `MyClass*` argument?

Comment: "is it possible?" you better try out and see what happens. When you have code with a compiler error it is much simpler to help you. Currently the question is unclear