# GCC 4.8 with GNU STL produces bad code for std::string constructor?

Tags: c++, gcc, stl, undefined-behavior

So a bit of C++ code:

```
void func( const std::string& theString )
{
    std::string theString( theString );
    theString += " more string";
    std::cout << theString;
}
```

which compiles fine with `GCC 4.8` and `VS 2013`. From my C++ knowledge, the code is okay with a local variable `theString` being brought into scope which then hides `theString` from the function argument. At the point of `theString` construction, the only `theString` in scope is the function argument which is passed to the `std::string` constructor. The constructed `std::string` is then named `theString` which comes into scope and is `theString` used later in the code. Phew!

However, `GCC` seems to act like `theString` passed to the `std::string` constructor is the local `theString` (which hasn't been constructed yet) causing the compiled program to crash. With VS 2013 the code compiles and runs fine.

So,

1. Is my code correct? Or am I doing something outside spec which means the GCC behaviour is undefined.
2. Is this a bug in GCC?

Comment: At the very least, your code is awful. You should never code like that, since it is unreadable (for humans).

Comment: 1. No. 2. No. You are initializing a string with its (uninitialized) self.

Comment: So the bug is more likely inside VS2013, if there is one. But your code is wrong.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch Although if it is UB, then the VS2013 behaviour is "ok".

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch Agreed, it's horrible stuff. Sadly it can crop up and knowing what is "right" by the compiler is important :) btw Thanks for all the responses!

Comment: p.s. is there a warning I can turn on to detect this misuse?

Comment: Your `cout` line has `tsString` instead of `theString`, is that a typo?

Comment: When I compile this with GCC 4.8.2 I get `error: declaration of ‘std::string theString’ shadows a parameter`.  No extra options needed.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using newly declared variable in initialization (int x = x+1)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9820027/using-newly-declared-variable-in-initialization-int-x-x1)

Comment: @Nate Eldredge fixed typo

Comment: @AndrewMedico the proposed duplicate really does not cover this case, which I describe in my answer. The other answers are very superficial to the point of being unhelpful in actually understanding what is going on.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

No, your code is invalid.

According to the C++ Standard (3.3.2 Point of declaration)

> 1 The point of declaration for a name is immediately after its
>   complete declarator (Clause 8) and before its initializer (if any),
>   except as noted below.

```
[ Example:
int x = 12;
{ int x = x; }
```

> Here the second x is initialized with its own (indeterminate) value.
>   —end example ]

And (3.3.3 Block scope, #2)

> A parameter name **shall not be redeclared** in the outermost block of the
>   function definition nor in the outermost block of any handler
>   associated with a function-try-block.

Comment: The canonical questions for that example in `3.3.2` are: for C++11 [Does initialization entail lvalue-to-rvalue conversion? Is `int x = x;` UB?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14935722/1708801) and for C++14 [Has C++ standard changed with respect to the use of indeterminate values and undefined behavior in C++1y?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23415661/1708801)

Answer (score 14):

This is [undefined behaviour in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9820027/using-newly-declared-variable-in-initialization-int-x-x1). [paxdiablo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9820155/3920237) quotes the C++03 standard:

> The point of declaration for a name is immediately after its complete 
>   declarator (clause 8) and before its initializer (if any) ...
>
> Example:
>
> ```
> int x = 12;
> { int x = x; }
> ```
>
> Here the second x is initialized with its own (indeterminate) value.

Answer (score 2):

Although the current answers are basically correct, this is undefined behavior because you are using an indeterminate value the details are a bit more involved. For primitive types I believe either [Does initialization entail lvalue-to-rvalue conversion? Is int x = x; UB?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14935722/1708801) or [Has C++ standard changed with respect to the use of indeterminate values and undefined behavior in C++1y?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23415661/1708801) provide sufficient detail to understand why the behavior is undefined.

For a user defined type though I don't think they fill in enough of the details. We can see from this rather old but relevant [defect report 63: Initialization of class from self](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2005/n1931.html#363) which asks:

> And if so, what is the semantics of the self-initialization of UDT?

and provides an example in which only the reference and the address is taken of the class under construction and the answer says:

> 3.8  basic.life paragraph 6 indicates that the references here are valid. It's permitted to take the address of a class object before it
>   is fully initialized, and it's permitted to pass it as an argument to
>   a reference parameter as long as the reference can bind directly.

It is referring to section `3.8` *Object lifetime* because the object is under construction and its storage has been allocated but it lifetime has not began because its initialization is not complete.

If we look at paragraph `6` from section `3.8` it says (*emphasis mine*):

> Similarly, **before the lifetime of an object has started but after the
>   storage which the object will occupy has been allocated** or, after the
>   lifetime of an object has ended and before the storage which the
>   object occupied is reused or released, any glvalue that refers to the
>   original object may be used but only in limited ways. For an object
>   under construction or destruction, see 12.7. Otherwise, such a glvalue
>   refers to allocated storage (3.7.4.2), and using the properties of the
>   glvalue that do not depend on its value is well-defined. **The program
>   has undefined behavior if**:

and includes:

> the glvalue is used to access a non-static data member or call a
>   non-static member function of the object,

So before the initialization is complete we can not take the value of a non-static data member which clearly will be required during copy construction of a `std::string`.