# Assigning an uninitialized string to itself during initialization

Tags: c++, initialization

Is the following program really valid C++?

```
#include <string>   
int main () {
    std::string x = x;
    return 0;
}
```

It compiles without errors or warnings with g++ and just seg faults when run.

If I change the type of x to `int`, it gives me a warning at least: `warning: "x" is used uninitialized in this function [-Wuninitialized]`.

I would have expected the line to be invalid because `x` has not been declared before.

Comment: Related to [Has C++ standard changed with respect to the use of indeterminate values and undefined behavior in C++1y?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23415661/1708801) my analysis in this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26767656/1708801) is also relevant ... that question is possibly a duplicate.

Comment: Thanks for sharing this. I had not realized that this is actually an infamous example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is well-formed. The point of declaration of the variable's name comes after the declarator `std::string x`, and before the initialiser `= x`, so the variable's name can be used in its own initialiser.

This allows well-defined initialisations that don't use the value, like:

```
void * p = &p;
```

but unfortunately also allows the uninitialised value to be used in examples like yours, with undefined behaviour.

Comment: Thanks for sharing that reasonable example. I'd still consider it a language bug that the original example has not been forbidden by the standard.

Answer (score 1):

This is undefined behavior. As you are initialising one object with uninitialized object.

Comment: I realize that. But I would have expected this to be a corner case that could easily have been defined as invalid C++, resulting in a compiler error.

Comment: Why compiler would complain... Its syntactically right but logically wrong.

Comment: In a better world the line would be syntactically wrong C++.

Comment: Compilers give fatal error for syntactically correct programs all the time.  char * a; int b = a;