# What does this incremental syntax mean?

Tags: c++, syntax, increment

I came across a line of code that is quite confusing to me. I tried searching but wasn't sure what to even search for.

The line is as follows:

```
 int i = ++::i;
```

I am lost to whether this line evaluates to:

```
 int i+= i ;
```

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In

```
int i = ++::i;
```

the `::` is there to tell the compiler use the `i` from the global scope.  Without it the compiler is going to use the `i` you just declared which is undefined behavior.  For more on that see [Using newly declared variable in initialization (int x = x+1)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9820027/using-newly-declared-variable-in-initialization-int-x-x1)