# Why capture lambda does not working in c++?

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda, std, capture

I am playing with lambda expressions in C++, and I have tried a few things to see the outcome. I actually watched the video in CppCon [Back to Basics: Lambdas from Scratch - Arthur O'Dwyer - CppCon 2019](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3jCOwajNch0&t=651s) @21:47 and started to play with lambdas.

As an example, I've tried this:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int g = 10;//global var 'g'

//creating lambda
auto kitten = [=] () {return g+1;};
auto cat = [g=g] () {return g+1;};
// main
int main()
{
    g = 20;//modifying global variable 'g'
    cout<<"kitten: "<<kitten()<<"cat: "<<cat()<<endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Output of the above code is:

```
kitten: 21cat: 11
```

In the above example: `[g=g]` means capture a data member whose name is `g` and whose type is the same as the outer `g`, as if I had written `auto g=g`. It's a copy of `g`. Which makes sense when we think that (as if I had written in the form of `auto g=g`) so the result is 11 in our case, where modification of the global `g` is not reflected in our `local g`.

**The result for the kitten is 21** because as far as I understand, capture everything i.e., capture all external variable by value.

Then, when it comes to this example by modifying the first lambda as follows:

```cpp
auto kitten = [] () {int g  = g; return g+1;};
```

Where I declared `local g` and assigned value from `global g`, the output is:

```cpp
kitten: 1cat: 11
```

But I was expecting the output as in the first example (21) because I am trying the create a local `g` and assigning its value from the global `g`, where it is already the modified value of 20.

Codes are compiled on https://techiedelight.com/compiler/ and godbolt.org with c++ (GCC 8.3.0) (with the latest compiler, `[=]` this is not allowed, but the results are the same).

At this moment, I am a little confused about the concept of capturing and/or lambda.

Comment: `[g=g]` is the same as `[auto g=g]` and is what you are doing.  `=` means copy in a lambda capture, `&` means reference.

Comment: @NathanOliver Except that `[auto g=g]` isn't a real syntax. (If one really needs to force a type on an init-capture, there's `[v=static_cast<T>(e)]`.)

Comment: @Yakk - Adam Nevraumont It can be compiled from here:https://techiedelight.com/compiler/ with gcc 8.3.0 as already stated in the post! Please read carefully and try out there.

Comment: unless capture list is empty and no external non-constexpr symbols are referenced in lambda expression's body, this lambda does perform capturing. One  reliable sign of capture-less lambda expression is that it can bound to a pointer to function.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
auto kitten = [=] () {return g+1;}
```

This lambda doesn't capture anything at all. It's nearly the same as just

```
int kitten() { return g+1; }
```

Only local variables can be captured, and there are no local variables visible in the scope of the `kitten` definition. Note that `[=]` or `[&]` don't mean "capture everything", they mean "capture anything necessary", and a global variable is never necessary (or possible) to capture in a lambda, since the meaning of that variable name is always the same no matter when the lambda body is evaluated.

---

```
auto cat = [g=g] () {return g+1;}
```

Here's an init-capture, which is similar to creating a local variable and immediately capturing it. The `g` before the equal sign declares the init-capture, and the `g` after the equal sign specifies how to initialize it. Unlike most declarators (see below), the `g` variable created here is not in scope in its own initializer, so the `g` after the equal sign means the global variable `::g`. So the code is similar to:

```
auto make_cat()
{
    int & g = ::g;
    return [g]() { return g+1; }
}
auto cat = make_cat();
```

---

```
auto kitten = [] () {int g  = g; return g+1;}
```

This code has a mistake not really related to lambdas. In the local variable definition `int g = g;`, the declared variable before the equal sign is in scope during the initializer after the equal sign. So `g` is initialized with its own indeterminate value. Adding one to that indeterminate value is undefined behavior, so the result is not predictable.

Answer (score 7):

> ```
> auto kitten = [] () {int g  = g; return g+1;};
> ```

You aren't using a global at all here. You're using the local `g` to initialise the local `g`. The behaviour of the program is undefined.

> why `int g = g;` trying to initialize local g by itself,

Because the initialiser is after the point where the local `g` has been declared.

> shouldn't that compiler initialize with the global g?

No.

Comment: Perhaps throw in a suggestion how to address the global: `auto kitten = [] () {int g = ::g; return g+1;};`

Comment: @eerorika Why is that so? We can create a local variable with the same name inside another function and in the main we can access the global `g` again.  My point is why int g = g; trying to initialize local `g` by itself, shouldn't that compiler initialize with the global g? from right to left? 
e.g:  calling function `foo()` and inside foo() int g= 33 will be local, in the main after the calling foo(), output of the global `g` is still remaining same? There is no problem accessing global var. inside another function but why is this init. is problematic?

Comment: @Ted Lyngmo, Yes, you are right, when we use `::` operator, it is working as expected! But I thought, by default, compiler should do this. As stated previous comment above, from right to left...

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9820027/using-newly-declared-variable-in-initialization-int-x-x1