# My division function returns a zero. Should I declare x differently in main?

Tags: c++

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int division(int c, int d);

int x = 2;
int y = 2;

int division(int c, int d)
{
    return (c/d);
}

int main()
{
    cout << "Hello World!\n";
    int x = division(x,y);
    cout << x;
    return 0;
}
```

I expected the code to show `1` after `Hello World!`, but it prints `0`.
I removed `int` from in front of `x` (in `main()`) and ran it again and it returned `1`.
But I also passed `x,x` to the division function with the `int` in front of `x` (in `main()`) and it returned `1`.

So I am not sure how the assignment statement is working.

Comment: The call to `division` isn't operating on the data you think it is. Try renaming the `int x` in `main` to `z`.

Comment: Useful reading, almost duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9820027/using-newly-declared-variable-in-initialization-int-x-x1

Comment: Check this out, https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_scope_rules.htm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This expression:

```cpp
int x = division(x,y);
```

is equivalent to writing this:

```cpp
// 'x' was defined globally somewhere here before
int x;
x = division(x, y);
```

This shadows the previous `x` variable defined globally and defines a local variable `x` which again is uninitialized so after passing it in the `division()` function, your code has [*Undefined Behavior*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). (When that happens, the output can be anything, it can be `0`, it can even be `1` or something else entirely.)

What you want to do is to remove the declaration and turn it into an assignment instead:

```cpp
x = division(x,y);
```

Then the above works properly and gives `1`.

Answer (score 2):

You should compile your code at least  with `-Wall` flag.
You would then see a helpful warning message:

```
foo.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
foo.cpp:17:21: warning: ‘x’ is used uninitialized [-Wuninitialized]
   17 |     int x = division(x,y);
      |             ~~~~~~~~^~~~~
```

It means that to the `division()` isn't passed global `x`, but the local one from `main()`.
It's undefinied behaviour, no different than `int z = division(z,y);`

After removing `int` from before `x` in `main()` you no longer declare local variable, thus there is only one `x` in your program (the global one) and from initialization the line turns into plain assignment.